# Errors trying to refresh openid-selector sprites on OSX

Tags: macos, openid-selector

I'm using [openid-selector](https://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/), I've updated the openid-en.js with news providers and now, following the readme.txt of the project, I should refresh sprite images with generate-sprite.sh.

But, when I try to run generate-sprite.sh on OSX terminal, the errors below are shown on output:

```
./generate-sprite.sh: ./remcomments.sed: /bin/sed: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
./generate-sprite.sh: ./remcomments.sed: /bin/sed: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
./generate-sprite.sh: line 70: montage: command not found
./generate-sprite.sh: line 71: montage: command not found
./generate-sprite.sh: line 72: convert: command not found
rm: small.bmp: No such file or directory
rm: large.bmp: No such file or directory
done
```

Does anyone knows what is wrong with command or what is missing on my OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. The './remcomments.sed: /bin/sed: bad interpreter' problem

---

Inside the ./remcomments.sed file that come with openid-selector there is this first line:

`#!/bin/sed -nf`

Well, in OSX the path for sed command is: /usr/bin/sed, so ***to fix the first problem, just change the first line of ./remcomments.sed to:***

`#!/usr/bin/sed -nf`

2. The 'montage: command not found' problem

---

There was no 'mountage' command on OSX. **To fix the second problem you will need to install [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx).**

With these two problems solved the generage-sprinte.sh will execute successful.